# Overleaf XeLatex article conversion to PdfLatex (for Arxiv submission). Problems with Arabic encoding

Tags: xetex, pdftex, arabic, arxiv, arabtex

as many others I am looking for a solution to upload my paper written in Overleaf (XeLatex) to Arxiv. The main problem is a specific character (ڨ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ve_(Arabic_letter) which is not rightly encoded. I am new to Latex so for sure I am doing something wrong. I have tried many different options such as \DeclareUnicodeCharacter, \usepackage{newunicodechar} as you can see here:

```
%\usepackage[cp 1256]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{arabtex}
% \usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
% \babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic} I also tried arabic-algerian
% \babelprovide[import, language=Default]{english}
% \babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
% \babelfont{sf}{Amiri} 
%\newunicodechar{ڨ}{\u{06A5}} I also tried {06A4} and {06A8}
\usepackage{tipa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E24}{\d{H}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0259}{\u{0259}} %schwa
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{ڨ}{\u{06A5}} I also tried {06A4} and {06A8}
```

in XeLatex I was using \usepackage{polyglossia} there is no way to use it also through PdfLatex right? 
Could someone suggest me some solution?

Thank you, 
Elisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `arabtex`+pdflatex with UTF8 input, you would also need to tell `arabtex` that your Arabic text are UTF8 rather than transliterations/transcriptions. Therefore adding `\usepackage{utf8}\setcode{utf8}` should help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{document}
Hello \RL{ڨ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just need to insert short Arabic text snippets, the `babel` package isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much LianTze Lim!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply recommend using LuaLaTeX, as you could then avoid using the outdated Arabtex and could simply input whatever Arabic you want directly.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,     % to get correct arabic shaping
    Scale=1.2]          % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
        {Arial}         % whatever Arabic font you like

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]     % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1]     % for digits inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote} [1]     % Arabic footnotes
    {\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}
\newenvironment{Arabic}         % Arabic paragraph
    {\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\begin{document}

I don't quite get the problem: \textarabic{ڨ}. It is really simple.

\end{document}
```

Comment: arXiv would accept only pdflatex or latex only, I think.

Comment: @LianTzeLim : ah yes, alright. I also overlooked that the questioner mentioned "XeLatex" specifically -- which brings me to the question, why she is not using XeLaTeX and directly types Arabic? That works with LuaLaTeX as it does with XeLaTeX (maybe even better in the latter's case), no?

Comment: The OP was indeed originally using polyglossia + xelatex in her project on Overleaf; but had to switch to pdflatex to submit to arXiv. Fortunately this glyph can be produced with pdflatex+arabtex (some can't); otherwise I think we will have to suggest use an `\includgraphics` as what I had to do many years ago...! (And yes, LuaLaTeX is more powerful especially when it comes to Arabic typesetting!)